# npm install firebase fails

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm

I'm trying to install firebase ^5.5.0 on my local environment (vagrant/virtualbox with ubuntu 16.0.4 and the newest npm and nodejs)

When I run `npm install` I get this error:

> npm ERR! path
>   /code/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/mkdirp/node_modules/minimist/package.json.789167206
>   npm ERR! code ENOENT npm ERR! errno -2 npm ERR! syscall open npm ERR!
>   enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   '/code/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/mkdirp/node_modules/minimist/package.json.789167206'
>   npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
>   npm ERR! enoent
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   /home/vagrant/.npm/_logs/2018-09-19T09_14_46_808Z-debug.log

The logs or verbose don't tell me anything other than this. How can I solve this?

Comment: If you are trying to install this globally to the system, run `npm install -g firebase` instead. That said, if you are trying to install firebase to a specific folder/project make sure you have a `package.json` present in the folder you run the command in.

Comment: Hi Carlo, thanks for your answer. It's actually running from a package.json - when I run npm install after adding it to the json file, I get this error.

Comment: Have you tried deleting your `package-lock.json` and your `node_modules` folder and re-running `npm install`?

Comment: Yes I have, it's of no result unfortunately. I'm also getting a new (replaced) error now after installing grpc and mkdirp:

`/code/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/mkdirp/node_modules/minimist/package.json.1879144488`

Where `/code/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/` does not exist on the system, only `firestore-types`

Comment: Could you post the complete error log as specified in the error message?

Comment: The entire log can be found here: https://paper.dropbox.com/doc/firebase-error-log--ANKuYbHaR_3V1T6MHKlo00VOAQ-k3lTHt7y8RWXBMfhNkFpV

Comment: Did you ever get Firebase installed? I'm also seeing this issue tracked here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1234#issuecomment-619361802

Comment: Yes, I just don't remember how. I believe I reinstalled everything.

Answer (score 0):

I did what @Carlo I deleted the `package-lock.json` and ran `npm install`, after auditing all the package I ran `npm install firebase` prior to funding and some audit fixes.
Maybe after funding or fixing some audits it may have been incompatible with installing firebase.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, for anyone who did the same thing as me, i.e being on autopilot during cloud functions setup :

- Ignore the error message
- Go to functions dir
- npm install